# Как сделать перенаправление поддериктории nginx на другой root

Tags: php, nginx

есть такой конфиг, немогу запустить index.php из поддиректории /tests/
root /var/www/devsdk/tests/test_api/web/index.php - реальное расположение файла;

```
root /var/www/devsdk/frontend/web;

index index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$args;
}


location /tests/ {
         #/var/www/devsdk/tests/test_api/web
    root /var/www/devsdk/tests/test_api/web;
    try_files  $uri/tests/ /tests/index.html /tests/index.php?$args;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(\/index\.php)(.*)$;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/web.sock;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте поменять `location` местами. Сейчас все входящие сразу же попадают в `location /` и дальше не идут

Comment: А не, перепутал `location` с регулярками. [Здесь](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration) описано как все работает. В вашем случае - `index.php` соответствует регулярке `~ \.php$` поэтому срабатывает она. Если назвать файл, например, как `index.phtml`, то должна будет браться откуда надо (т.к. не подходит под регулярку `\.php$`)

Comment: И лучше уточнить используемую версию, т.к. возможно [следующее](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location): `В версиях с 0.7.1 по 0.8.41, если запрос точно совпал с префиксным location’ом без модификаторов “=” и “^~”, то поиск тоже сразу же прекращается и регулярные выражения также не проверяются.`

Answer (score 1):

`root` задает виртуальный корень, к которому потом еще будет дописан путь из директивы `try_files`.

Поэтому ваш файл в итоге ищется как `/var/www/devsdk/tests/test_api/web/tests/index.php` - и, естественно, не находится.

Попробуйте использовать директиву `alias` вместо второго `root`.